# Excel VBA Find fails when called from spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
function fred
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim v
    Set ws = Worksheets("outfile")
    set v = ws.Cells.Find(18709)
    If v Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "nothing"
    if not v is nothing then debug.print v.address

exit function
```

The same code works (finds any value) when pasted into the debug window. But when called as an expression from a spread sheet, it fails, finding nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

- Functions need to be placed in a **module** or they won't work
- Call the user function from Excel with [A1]: `=fred()`
- you can return a value to Excel if you change your code slightly: `fred = v.Address`
- change `exit function` to `end function`

[image]

---

```
Function fred()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim v
    Set ws = Worksheets("outfile")
    Set v = ws.Cells.Find(18709)
    If v Is Nothing Then fred = "nothing"
    If Not v Is Nothing Then fred = v.Address
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, the problem is that the "FIND" *doesn't work*.  FIND returns "nothing" as shown by "If v is Nothing". I'm not having trouble using functions in Excel, I having trouble using FIND.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. The macro is working just find when called from a spreadsheet. It finds any "18709" value and outputs the address to the immediate pane. If this code is part of a greater macro, be aware that Excel remembers all unspecified FIND parameters (such as `after:=`, `lookat:=` or `lookin:=`) from earlier FIND functions within the macro. Specify them with default values. Maybe you can [upload your workbook?](http://ge.tt/)